# WPF unable to set Name Property on User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a custom UserControl (xaml + code behind). I need to set the name property when the UserControl is dropped on the VS designer surface.

I tried

```
this.Name = "testName";
```

I wrote this line in the constructor, in the initialized and loaded event...nothing. The name is not set. I tried with RegisterName, as shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name(v=vs.110).aspx

```
this.RegisterName("testName", this);
```

and

```
this.Name = "testName";
this.RegisterName(this.Name, this);
```

but...nothing.

How can I programmatically set the Name of a UserControl in WPF?

**NOTE:** when I say that nothing happens, I mean that in xaml the Name properti of my UserControl is note set. Instead of

```
<myUserControl name="testName" ... />
```

I see

```
<myUserControl ... />
```

Comment: do you call this before or after `InitializeComponent()` ?

Comment: on the OnInitialized

Comment: Do you expect the xaml to change when you set a property in code behind?

Comment: you mean it does not update the XAML?

Comment: Yes, as explained in the Note. Maybe do I need to change the question title?

Comment: @Riccardo How you could check the XAML in run time?

Comment: ...I need this feature at design-time. I'm programming a series of custom property editors for a User Control lib, and I need to set the name of myUserControl for binding purposes.

Comment: @Riccardo the xaml won't update when you set a property in code behind. XAML is a sort of compile time specification and is unaffected by what you do at run time

Comment: Not at Runtime...Property Editors work at Design-Time.

Answer (score 0):

To reach the goal I used the objects model of Visual Studio.

**Step 1**

Retrieve the Model Item of the object (the hardest part; this depends on your scenario, so there are no general solutions)

**Step2**

```
myUserControlModelItem.Properties["Name"].ComputedValue = "testName";
```